# populate dropdown using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with populating the dropdown list. The page is not showing the dropdown. It doesn't throw any exception either. I appreciate any help.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
  } 
  <?php 
     $SQL = "SELECT c_id, c_name FROM table1"; 
     $result = $mysqli->query($SQL);
   ?> 
 <select id="country" name="country">    
    <option value=''></option>    
  <?php 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
    {       
    echo "<option value='{$row['c_id']}'>{$row['c_name']}</option>\n";
   }   
?>  
</select>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$result` instead of `$cresult`?

Comment: It _should_ be showing the select. Can you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: Turn on errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` Hard to see what is wrong since you are using classes that we cannot see the code for.

Comment: this would be fine if you are on a dev server; but if it is on production; leave display errors to off and just the logs instead `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: I am getting Undefined variable: mysqli.

Comment: @nav100 That's odd - if your code is as above, `$mysqli` is defined even if it the connection failed and it isn't a valid resource.

Comment: Well this isn't the error but what you are doing is using fetch_object() yet you are calling it as an array... You should be using `$row->c_id` and `$row->c_name`

Comment: @nav100 What line does that error refer to?

Comment: I just replaced with echo "<option value=\"" .$row->c_id."\">".$row->c_name."</option>";. But still I have the problem. I would like to use prepared statements. So that's reason I am switching to mySQLi. The page works fine with mysql_connect. Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your query did not fail, since you fetched an object instead of an associative array, use the object operator to access properties (`->`)

```
while ($row = $cresult->fetch_object()) 
{       
  echo "<option value='{$row->c_id}'>{$row->c_name}</option>\n";
  //------------------------^^^----------^^^^
}
```